# SQL - Update a single column from the max value of multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which looks like this which I want to update:

#### Table A

```
[Id] IDENTITY INT NOT NULL
[Name] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
[Date] DATETIME NULL
```

And 5 other tables which look like this:

#### Tables B-F

```
[Id] IDENTITY INT NOT NULL
[TableAId] INT NOT NULL
[Date] DATETIME NOT NULL

CONSTRAINT [FK_TableB_TableA] FOREIGN KEY [TableAId] REFERENCES [TableA]([Id])
```

`[Date]` on Table A is a new column which should be non-nullable after the value is set. The value which is set needs to be the highest `[Date]` in any of the tables B-F. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Storing redundant information and updating it all the time isn't the best solution. Would a *View* work for you instead?

Comment: maybe Trigger can help in this case if data are not updating very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it should do the trick.

```
UPDATE [t]
SET [Date] = (
    SELECT MAX([Dates].[Date])
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX([Date]) AS [Date] FROM [TableB] WHERE [TableAId] = [t].[Id]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MAX([Date]) AS [Date] FROM [TableC] WHERE [TableAId] = [t].[Id]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MAX([Date]) AS [Date] FROM [TableD] WHERE [TableAId] = [t].[Id]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MAX([Date]) AS [Date] FROM [TableE] WHERE [TableAId] = [t].[Id]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MAX([Date]) AS [Date] FROM [TableF] WHERE [TableAId] = [t].[Id]
    ) AS [Dates]
)
FROM [TableA] AS [t]
```